# How can I place widget A in the center and the widget B to the edge?

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
        Row(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('hello');
                  },
                  child: Text('hmmm')),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I have this `Row` widget that has two widgets. I want to place the `hmmm` button widget in the center, while placing that white container widget in the right side of the edge. How can I do that inside the `Row` widget?

Comment: Do you want both 'hmm' and white container to remain in the same line? I mean when the 'hmm' comes to the center then should the white container stay in the edge of the center? or you want the white container to stay in the top left edge?

Comment: Yes, right. I am trying to add the `filter` icon to it. You know typically they are on the right edge to click.

Comment: Great, I guessed it right. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` and add a third element to be at the start

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this
  children: [
    Container(), // add this
    Center(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('hello');
        },
        child: Text('hmmm'),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 20,
      width: 20,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ],
),
```

output:

[image: output]

Row in DevTools:

[image: Row in DevTools]

Comment: Just quick added up! I had to make sure that `Sizedbox` has the same width (+ padding value - if I use one) in order to centre the `hmmm` widget in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to get this result:

[image]

You can either use a `Row` with `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` and add a `SizedBox()` like so:

```dart
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(),
                  Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('hello');
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'hmmm',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Or you could use a `Stack` widget with two children:

- A `Row` with you `hmmm` text.
- A `Positionned` widget with an `Align` widget as a child, and your white `Container` as a child of your `Align`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
      Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('hello');
                },
                child: Text('hmmm')
            ),
            Container(
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Let us know if this is what you wanted.